# Continuous pdf and cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, continuity, standard-deviation

Could someone explain what comes from pdf and what comes from cumulative distribution function (cdf) as far as: Probabilities ( $x < a,$ or $a < x < b$), standard deviation, Expected value, and variance?

Edit: to elaborate on what I've tried and where I am having a lapse in understanding,

I understand you can go from pdf to cumulative distribution function by taking the integral from negative infinity to infinity.

But once I have both, I'm having difficulty calculating probabilities, standard deviation and the mean due to not knowing when to use pdf vs cdf to calcuate it.

for example: to get the probability of x being between A and B, do I integrate from A to B the pdf dx, or do I integrate from A to B the cdf dx

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Specific question unclear.

Comment: I understand you can go from pdf to cumulative distribution function by taking the integral from negative infinity to infinity,  but once I have both, im having difficulty calculating probabilities, standard deviation and the mean due to not knowing when to use pdf vs cdf to calcuate it.  for example,  to get the probability of x being between A and B, do I integrate from A to B  the pdf dx, or do I integrate from A to B  the cdf dx

Comment: $P( x < b) = F(b) = \int_{-\infty}^b f(t) dt$ and $E(g(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) dF(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t) f(t) dt$. These are the connections ... notice since $x$ has a pdf, $F$ is continuous and $P(x = b)=0$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).